# converting specific string format to date in sparksql

Tags: date, apache-spark-sql

I have a column that contains a string with the following date as a string `Sat Sep 14 09:54:30 UTC 2019`. Not familiar with format at all.

I need to convert to date or timestamp. Just a unit that I can compare against. I just need a point of comparison with a precision of one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you get the timestamp from your string and then you get the days from it using Spark SQL(2.x)

```
spark.sql("""SELECT from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sat Sep 14 09:54:30 UTC 2019","EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy") ),"IST")as timestamp""").show()

+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2019-09-14 20:54:30|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! I was not familiar with that utc time format at all! Thanks!